# How to solve un-instantiated property that should be an Injectable class in NestJs application?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

The project has two modules where:

1. **UserModule** handles all operations on the user, it has a provider of type repository called `UserDepot` which depends on the `User` modle of `Sequelize` library.

```js
    @Module({
      imports: [
        SequelizeModule.forFeature([User])
      ],
      providers: [UserDepot],
      exports: [
        UserDepot
      ]
    })
    export class UserModule {
    }
```

2. **RegistrationModule** is responsible for registration process, this module imports UserModule so it can use `UserDepot`.

```js
    @Module({
      imports: [
        UserModule,
        MessagingModule,
        AuthenticationModule
      ],
      providers: [
        RegistrationService
      ],
      controllers: [
        RegistrationController
      ]
    })
    export class RegistrationModule {
    }
```

in RegistrationController there is an endpoint for phone registration where it has a validation pipe that checks if the phone number doesn't exist in the database.

```js
  @Post("phone")
  async phone(
    @Body(ValidationPipe, UniquePhoneValidatorPipe) dto: PhoneRegistrationDto
  ) {
    return await this.service.handlePhoneRegistration(dto.phone);
  }
```

The validation pipe checks the existence by this code:

```js
  constructor(private readonly users: UserDepot) {
  }

  async transform(dto: PhoneRegistrationDto, _: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (await this.isNotUniquePhone(dto.phone)) {
      throw new ConflictException("Phone number already exists");
    }

    return dto;
  }

  private async isNotUniquePhone(phone: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return !(await this.users.existByPhone(phone));
  }
```

***The problem***
When calling the endpoint, an exception with the quoted message is thrown:

> [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'existByPhone' of undefined

It's like nest is not instantiating the instance of `UserDepot`.

- Dependency is not an issue since the project runs without errors while compilation `(npm run start:dev)`
- `UserDepot` is decorated with `@Injectable`

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class UserDepot {
      constructor(
        @InjectModel(User)
        private readonly users: typeof User
      ) {
      }
    }
```

- `UserDepot` is imported properly (as far as i know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in my validation pipe in which the class in missing `@Injectable()` decotator.